# How to convert a C string (char array) into a Python string when there are non-ASCII characters in the string?

Tags: python, c, character-encoding, embedding

I have embedded a Python interpreter in a C program.  Suppose the C program reads some bytes from a file into a char array and learns (somehow) that the bytes represent text with a certain encoding (e.g., ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252, or UTF-8).  How do I decode the contents of this char array into a Python string?

The Python string should in general be of type `unicode`—for instance, a `0x93` in Windows-1252 encoded input becomes a `u'\u0201c'`.

I have attempted to use `PyString_Decode`, but it always fails when there are non-ASCII characters in the string.  Here is an example that fails:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char c_string[] = { (char)0x93, 0 };
     PyObject *py_string;

     Py_Initialize();

     py_string = PyString_Decode(c_string, 1, "windows_1252", "replace");
     if (!py_string) {
          PyErr_Print();
          return 1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The error message is `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`, which indicates that the `ascii` encoding is used even though we specify `windows_1252` in the call to `PyString_Decode`.

The following code works around the problem by using `PyString_FromString` to create a Python string of the undecoded bytes, then calling its `decode` method:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char c_string[] = { (char)0x93, 0 };
     PyObject *raw, *decoded;

     Py_Initialize();

     raw = PyString_FromString(c_string);
     printf("Undecoded: ");
     PyObject_Print(raw, stdout, 0);
     printf("\n");
     decoded = PyObject_CallMethod(raw, "decode", "s", "windows_1252");
     Py_DECREF(raw);
     printf("Decoded: ");
     PyObject_Print(decoded, stdout, 0);
     printf("\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: To nit-pick, a C string is a char[], not a char*

Comment: To nit-pick, when referencing a value, it doesn't matter. Arrays are passed as pointers to functions, anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyString_Decode does this:

```
PyObject *PyString_Decode(const char *s,
              Py_ssize_t size,
              const char *encoding,
              const char *errors)
{
    PyObject *v, *str;

    str = PyString_FromStringAndSize(s, size);
    if (str == NULL)
    return NULL;
    v = PyString_AsDecodedString(str, encoding, errors);
    Py_DECREF(str);
    return v;
}
```

IOW, it does basically what you're doing in your second example - converts to a string, then decode the string.  The problem here arises from PyString_AsDecodedString, rather than PyString_AsDecodedObject.  PyString_AsDecodedString does PyString_AsDecodedObject, but then tries to convert the resulting unicode object into a string object with the default encoding (for you, looks like that's ASCII).  That's where it fails.

I believe you'll need to do two calls - but you can use PyString_AsDecodedObject rather than calling the python "decode" method.  Something like:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char c_string[] = { (char)0x93, 0 };
     PyObject *py_string, *py_unicode;

     Py_Initialize();

     py_string = PyString_FromStringAndSize(c_string, 1);
     if (!py_string) {
          PyErr_Print();
          return 1;
     }
     py_unicode = PyString_AsDecodedObject(py_string, "windows_1252", "replace");
     Py_DECREF(py_string);

     return 0;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the reasoning behind PyString_Decode working this way is.  A [very old thread on python-dev](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-May/014547.html) seems to indicate that it has something to do with chaining the output, but since the Python methods don't do the same, I'm not sure if that's still relevant.

Comment: For Python3 https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromString

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to decode the string into a Unicode representation, you just want to treat it as an array of bytes, right?

Just use `PyString_FromString`:

```
char *cstring;
PyObject *pystring = PyString_FromString(cstring);
```

That's all.  Now you have a Python `str()` object.  See docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html

I'm a little bit confused about how to specify "str" or "unicode."  They are quite different if you have non-ASCII characters.  If you want to decode a C string **and** you know exactly what character set it's in, then yes, `PyString_DecodeString` is a good place to start.

Comment: I want to actually decode it, so whatever Python code ends up using the string does not need to know how it was originally encoded (in the input to the C program).  Thanks for pointing that I was being unclear; I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling [`PyErr_Print()`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html) in the "`if (!py_string)`" clause.  Perhaps the python exception will give you some more information.

Comment: Thanks, I did and incorporated the information into the question.